# How can I Enter into postgres bash command line and exit using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm beginner in writing script in linux. Can anyone please help!

From terminal I enter into postgres bash command line by typing:

[root@localhost Desktop]# su - postgres

-bash-3.2$

then I can create user,db from there and I can exit by typing "exit" command.

How can I do this by script? I've written a scrip but that does enter into bash but doesn't run the commands. I want to enter into bash, create a user & db then exit. My scripts concept is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash
createuser -P -s -e asterisk
createdb --owner=asterisk asterisk2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run your script this way:

```
su -c myscript.sh postgres
```

That is, run `myscript.sh` (or whatever it's called) as the `postgres` user.  No need for an interactive prompt, which is what `-` was giving you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
su postgres -c "createuser -P -s -e asterisk && createdb --owner=asterisk asterisk2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply.
Now it is asking me for db password. I enter it twice. Whats the 3rd password it is asking me?

[root@localhost Desktop]# bash test1.sh
Enter password for new role: 
Enter it again: 
Password: 
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
[root@localhost Desktop]#

Comment: Yes: the first password is for su'ing to postgres user (you should know 'postgres' user password; otherwise reset it - as root - with command `passwd postgres`). The second one is the password for the new role ("asterisk") you are creating; the third one is the confirmation.